# Problems installing Ubuntu Tweak

Tags: 10.04, package-management, dpkg

I'm new to Ubuntu and loving it already. I installed Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and want to download and install Ubuntu Tweak. I followed the following process: system>administrator>synaptic package manager...that were I can't proceed and received an error message:

E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.

What am I to do to rectify this problem, without reinstalling Ubuntu

Regards, Hylton

Comment: Please go to `Applications > Accessories > Terminal`, run the command `sudo dpkg --configure -a` (your password will not appear as you type it; just enter it and hit `enter`), and edit your question to include the results (you can just copy/paste them in).

Comment: Oh, and please format the output as code (select it and hit `ctrl+k`). That'll make it scrollable and easier to read.  :-)

Comment: It worked...I can find Ubuntu Teak under installed apps...am I supposed to see an icon?...thanx a million

Comment: Can you see the Ubuntu Tweak icon under `Applications -> System Tools` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please open a Terminal from `Applications>Accessories>Terminal` then copy and paste this following line

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Enter your password,wait some time and done.

Comment: This will probably not solve the problem. It will only display the error that has caused the problem. But it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: It worked...I can find Ubuntu Teak under installed apps...am I supposed to see an icon?...thanx a million!

Comment: don't forget to click the tick mark to make it the best answer.

Comment: Wow, I've never seen that command work on the first try. Good work, ssj6akshat! namkid, you should find Ubuntu Tweak somewhere in the menu. Just scan through the submenus in Applications and System. When you find it, don't forget to mark ssj6akshat's answer as correct by clicking the checkmark.